# How to sort data into a table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have data like this:

```
{
    "date": "2018-07-01",
    "hotel": "Hotel1",
    "room": "H1Room1",
    "qty": 3   
},
{
    "date": "2018-07-02",
    "hotel": "Hotel1",
    "room": "H1Room1",
    "qty": 3 
},
{
    "date": "2018-07-03",
    "hotel": "Hotel1",
    "room": "H1Room1",
    "qty": 2
},
{
    "date": "2018-07-01",
    "hotel": "Hotel1",
    "room": "H1Room2",
    "qty": 3   
},
{
    "date": "2018-07-02",
    "hotel": "Hotel1",
    "room": "H1Room2",
    "qty": 2   
},
{
    "date": "2018-07-01",
    "hotel": "Hotel2",
    "room": "H2Room1",
    "qty": 2 
},
{
    "date": "2018-07-02",
    "hotel": "Hotel2",
    "room": "H2Room1",
    "qty": 1 
}
```

And I want to put it on a table using Javascript. 
 
And the Output would like this: 
hotel    | room        | 2018-07-01 | 2018-07-02 | 2018-07-03 
hotel1  |H1Room1| 3                  | 3                 | 2 
hotel1  |H1Room2| 2                  | 1 
hotel2  |H2Room1| 2                  | 1

if possible using a for loop.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: none, just get started and it is required using for loop. I'm really having trouble thinking about this.

Comment: I'm really a beginner at this..

Comment: @HitoriZetsubo, I have added a snippet in an answer. Mark it as an answer if it helps. You can run the code snippet in order to check table.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var HotelDetails = [{
    "date": "2018-07-01",
    "hotel": "Hotel1",
    "room": "H1Room1",
    "qty": 3   
},
{
    "date": "2018-07-02",
    "hotel": "Hotel1",
    "room": "H1Room1",
    "qty": 3 
},
{
    "date": "2018-07-03",
    "hotel": "Hotel1",
    "room": "H1Room1",
    "qty": 2
},
{
    "date": "2018-07-01",
    "hotel": "Hotel1",
    "room": "H1Room2",
    "qty": 3   
},
{
    "date": "2018-07-02",
    "hotel": "Hotel1",
    "room": "H1Room2",
    "qty": 2   
},
{
    "date": "2018-07-01",
    "hotel": "Hotel2",
    "room": "H2Room1",
    "qty": 2 
},
{
    "date": "2018-07-02",
    "hotel": "Hotel2",
    "room": "H2Room1",
    "qty": 1 
}]

$(document).ready(function(){
CreateHTMLTable();
});

var DateArray = [];

function CreateHTMLTable()
{
  var ResultHTML = "<table class='table'><tr>";
  var TableHeader = "<th>Hotel</th><th>Room</th>";
  var TableRow = "";
  for(var k in HotelDetails) 
  {
    if(HotelDetails[k].date != "" && !CheckDateArray(HotelDetails[k].date))
    {
      TableHeader += "<th>" + HotelDetails[k].date + "</th>";
      DateArray.push(HotelDetails[k].date);
    }        
  }    
  
  ResultHTML += TableHeader + TableRow + "</tr><table>";
  $('#Hotel_Details').append(ResultHTML);
}

function CheckDateArray(datestr)
{
  if(DateArray.indexOf(datestr) > -1)
    return true;
  else 
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="Hotel_Details"></div>
```

Comment: @Hitori Zetsubo, check this snippet.

Comment: Yeah, it is good and simple. But it is different to the requirement that I'm going to make.

Comment: Then provide your proper requirement.@HitoriZetsubo

Comment: The Dates are also part of the header

Comment: @HitoriZetsubo, I updated script, dates are used as the header.

Answer (score 0):

A Pure VanillaJS way.

Try this:

```js
var json_data = [
  {
      "date": "2018-07-01",
      "hotel": "Hotel1",
      "room": "H1Room1",
      "qty": 3
  },
  {
      "date": "2018-07-02",
      "hotel": "Hotel1",
      "room": "H1Room1",
      "qty": 3
  },
  {
      "date": "2018-07-03",
      "hotel": "Hotel1",
      "room": "H1Room1",
      "qty": 2
  },
  {
      "date": "2018-07-01",
      "hotel": "Hotel1",
      "room": "H1Room2",
      "qty": 3
  },
  {
      "date": "2018-07-02",
      "hotel": "Hotel1",
      "room": "H1Room2",
      "qty": 2
  },
  {
      "date": "2018-07-01",
      "hotel": "Hotel2",
      "room": "H2Room1",
      "qty": 2
  },
  {
      "date": "2018-07-02",
      "hotel": "Hotel2",
      "room": "H2Room1",
      "qty": 1
  }
];

var rows = "";

for(item in json_data) {
  rows += "<tr>" +
  "<td>" + json_data[item].date + "</td>" +
  "<td>" + json_data[item].hotel + "</td>" +
  "<td>" + json_data[item].room + "</td>" +
  "<td>" + json_data[item].qty + "</td>" +
  "</tr>";
}

document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML = rows;
```

```html
<table id="mytable" border="1">

</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to merge the hotel and room on to corresponding dates?